# Minecraft re-downloads "Resources" folder on each start?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Strangely, with the new 1.2.5 update, if you ever force update or redownload the game to clear mods it doesn't download the audio files with at that point, it downloads them in the background as you play. But, with my setup, it downloads them again every time I start it! It's come to the point where I have to leave the game running at the main menu or risk sounds never coming back if my internet cuts off or something. How can I fix this? Is there a way to permanently backup the resources folder, so that Minecraft doesn't re-download them?

What makes this even weirder is that Mojang states the game can be played offline at any time as long as you have been online once to verify account is paid for. But lately people can't do that I guess, if I'm not the only one suffering this, as they would magically delete the audio files and require internet to get them back.

Maybe my game's bugged? I have'nt done a full erase of `.minecraft` in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to completely delete your `.minecraft` folder, and make sure you're using the latest client by re-downloading it from minecraft.net.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted my entire .minecraft folder and got a fresh new client from www.minecraft.net. No audio problems so far! Thanks again.